# How to pass a python variable to a string url in html using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using a flask server to run my web page. I this case I need to pass the variable data to a path URL which was received from flask app.py.

I tried this way its not working.

```
<iframe src="{{ url_for('static', filename='export/{{folder_name}}/head_data.html') }}" width="1000" height="550"></iframe>
```

Comment: What is it actually doing?

Comment: @TimRoberts
one folder name i am passing from python file to html, that name i need to pass in the above filename='export/my_file_name/head_data.html to render the page

Answer (score -1):

In the end I did:

```
src="static/export/{{folder_name}}/head_data.html"
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).